# Excel VBA - Deleting objects from sheet triggers run-time error

Tags: excel, runtime-error, vba

I am getting this run-time error "The index into the specified collection is out of bounds."

The goal is to remove all objects from my worksheet.
I was using the code below for quite some time and it worked fine before it suddenly started triggering the error.

```
Dim obj As Shape

For Each obj In .Shapes
    obj.Delete
Next obj
```

I did research online and found that looping backwards seemed to solve the problem for most people.

```
'Delete all objects on sheet
For i = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Req Raw").Shapes.count To 1 Step -1
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Req Raw").Shapes(i).Delete
Next
```

However, even with this code the error seems to persist, even with empty sheets with no objects. The sheet is not protected. On debug, the line in question seems to be the line with `delete`

Edit: Full code

The goal of this code is to take a table from the user's clipboard and paste it into an excel sheet called "Req Raw". It then reformats the table to a conformed format and copies a few values to a seperate sheet called 'Values'

Before any of the formatting can take place, the script bugs out due to the `.shapes.delete` line. It used to function properly and I had moved on in my script and hadn't even touched it in a few days. Now it is giving me the run-time error.

```html
Private Sub R2OK_Click()
'~~~> Variables
'Table Formatting Variables
Dim HC As Integer
Dim RID As Range
Dim RCount As Range
Dim RC As Integer
Dim RCon As Range
Dim RCon2 As Range
Dim CCount As Range
'Destination Cell
Dim MCell As Range
'End Rows
Dim EndR As Range
Dim cacheR As Range
'Object deletion
Dim obj As Shape
'ID Req Raw Rows
Dim SecT As Range
Dim IDCount As Integer
Dim IDF As String
'Values List
Dim VSection As Range
Dim VName As Range
Dim VType As Range
Dim VID As Range

'~~~> Set Active Sheet to Req Raw
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Req Raw")

'~~~> Paste DRS from Clipboard to empty row
    'Find next empty row
    HC = 2
    For Each RCount In Range("'Req Raw'!$A$" & HC & ":$A$50000")
        If RCount.Value <> 0 And RCount.Value <> "" Then
            HC = HC + 1
        ElseIf RCount = 0 Or RCCount = "" Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next RCount

    'Paste into empty cell
    ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Req Raw").Range("$B$" & HC)
    
    'Clear clipboard
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
    'Unmerge cells
    .Cells.UnMerge
    
    'Delete all objects on sheet
    For i = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Req Raw").Shapes.count To 1 Step -1
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Req Raw").Shapes(i).Delete '~~~PROBLEM LINE~~~
    'For Each obj In .Shapes
        'obj.Delete
    'Next obj
    Next

    'Find empty header columns and consolidate column contents where contents are marked by borders
    For Each CCount In Range("'Req Raw'!$AB$2:$B$2")
        If CCount.Value = "" Or CCount.Value = 0 Then
            For Each RCon In .Range(.Cells(3, CCount.Column), .Cells(.Cells(Rows.count, CCount.Column).End(xlUp).Row, CCount.Column))
                If RCon.Value <> "" And RCon.Value <> 0 Then
                    'Check to see that a cell within the word table row has not been split. If so, move cell contents to the cell above before merging across
                    If RCon.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle <> xlNone Then
                    ElseIf RCon.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlNone Then
                        For Each RCon2 In .Range(.Cells(RCon.Offset(1).Row, CCount.Column), .Cells(.Cells(Rows.count, CCount.Column).End(xlUp).Row, CCount.Column))
                            If RCon2.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle <> xlNone Then
                                If RCon2.Value <> "" And RCon2.Value <> 0 Then
                                    RCon.Value = RCon.Value & vbNewLine & RCon2.Value
                                    RCon2.ClearContents
                                End If
                                Exit For
                            ElseIf RCon2.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlNone And RCon2.Value <> "" And RCon2.Value <> 0 Then
                                RCon.Value = RCon.Value & vbNewLine & RCon2.Value
                                RCon2.ClearContents
                            End If
                        Next RCon2
                    End If
                End If
            Next RCon
            'If next column is a header column, check to see if data needs to be moved in that column
            If CCount.Offset(columnOffset:=-1).Value <> "" And CCount.Offset(columnOffset:=-1).Value <> 0 Then
                Set RCon = Nothing
                Set RCon2 = Nothing
                For Each RCon In .Range(.Cells(3, CCount.Column), .Cells(.Cells(Rows.count, CCount.Column).End(xlUp).Row, CCount.Column))
                    If RCon.Value <> "" And RCon.Value <> 0 Then
                        'Check to see that a cell within the word table row has not been split. If so, move cell contents to the cell above before merging across
                        If RCon.Offset(columnOffset:=-1).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle <> xlNone Then
                        ElseIf RCon.Offset(columnOffset:=-1).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlNone Then
                            For Each RCon2 In .Range(.Cells(RCon.Offset(1).Row, CCount.Offset(columnOffset:=-1).Column), .Cells(.Cells(Rows.count, CCount.Offset(columnOffset:=-1).Column).End(xlUp).Row, CCount.Offset(columnOffset:=-1).Column))
                                If RCon2.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle <> xlNone Then
                                    If RCon2.Value <> "" And RCon2.Value <> 0 Then
                                        RCon.Offset(columnOffset:=-1).Value = RCon.Offset(columnOffset:=-1).Value & vbNewLine & RCon2.Value
                                        RCon2.ClearContents
                                    End If
                                    Exit For
                                ElseIf RCon2.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlNone And RCon2.Value <> "" And RCon2.Value <> 0 Then
                                    RCon.Offset(columnOffset:=-1).Value = RCon.Offset(columnOffset:=-1).Value & vbNewLine & RCon2.Value
                                    RCon2.ClearContents
                                End If
                            Next RCon2
                        End If
                    End If
                Next RCon
            End If
        End If
    Next CCount

    'Find empty header columns and move data from left to right until header is not blank, while deleting empty cells
    Set CCount = Nothing
    Set RCon = Nothing
    For Each CCount In Range("'Req Raw'!$AB$2:$B$2")
        If CCount.Value = "" Or CCount.Value = 0 Then
            For Each RCon In .Range(.Cells(3, CCount.Column), .Cells(.Cells(Rows.count, CCount.Column).End(xlUp).Row, CCount.Column))
                If RCon.Value <> "" And RCon.Value <> 0 Then
                    RCon.Offset(columnOffset:=-1).Value = RCon.Offset(columnOffset:=-1).Value & vbNewLine & RCon.Value
                    If CCount.Offset(columnOffset:=-1).Value <> "" And CCount.Offset(columnOffset:=-1).Value <> 0 Then
                        RCon.Offset(columnOffset:=-1).Value = RCon.Offset(columnOffset:=-1).Value & vbNewLine
                    End If
                End If
            Next RCon
            CCount.EntireColumn.Delete
        End If
    Next CCount

    ''Row Management Begins
    Set CCount = Nothing
    Set RCon = Nothing
    RC = HC + 1
    
    'Check for empty row between header and first testcase
    Do
    Set RID = Range("'Req Raw'!$B$" & RC)
    If RID = "" Or RID = 0 Then
        For Each CCount In Range("'Req Raw'!$B$2:$AB$2")
            If CCount.Offset(1).Value <> "" And CCount.Offset(1).Value <> 0 Then
            CCount.Value = CCount.Value & vbNewLine & CCount.Offset(1).Value
            End If
            If CCount.Value = 0 Or CCount.Value = "" Then Exit For
        Next CCount
        CCount.Offset(1).EntireRow.Delete
        Set CCount = Nothing
    End If
    Set RID = Range("'Req Raw'!$B$" & RC)
    Loop Until RID <> "" And RID <> 0
    
    'Loop for each Test Case
    Do Until RC = 0

        'Find end row (end of requirement)
        For Each EndR In Range("'Req Raw'!$B$" & (RC + 1) & ":$B$" & (RC + 101))
            If EndR <> "" And EndR <> 0 Then Exit For
            If EndR.Row = RC + 101 Then
                Set cacheR = Range("'Values'!$B$3")

                For Each CCount In Range("'Req Raw'!$B$2:$AB$2")
                    cacheR.Offset(columnOffset:=1).Value = Worksheets("Req Raw").Cells(Rows.count, CCount.Column).End(xlUp).Row
                    cacheR = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(cacheR.Value, cacheR.Offset(columnOffset:=1).Value)
                    'If CCount (Header) is blank, then exit
                    If CCount.Value = 0 Or CCount.Value = "" Then Exit For
                Next CCount
                Set EndR = Range("'Req Raw'!$A$" & cacheR.Value)
                Exit For
            End If
                
        Next EndR
        
        Set CCount = Nothing
        
        'Consolidate cell contents (rows)
            'For Each Column
            For Each CCount In Range("'Req Raw'!$B$2:$AB$2")
            'Where CCount (Header) is not blank
                If CCount.Value <> 0 And CCount.Value <> "" Then
                    'Set destination cell in CCount column
                    Set MCell = Sheets("Req Raw").Cells(RC, CCount.Column)
                    'For Each cell in CCount Column within RC (Header) + 1 and EndR Row (Next Header) - 1
                    For Each RCon In .Range(.Cells(RC, CCount.Column), .Cells(EndR.Row - 1, CCount.Column))
                    'Range ("'Req Raw'!" & CCount.Columns(1) & (RC + 1) & ":" & CCount.Columns(1) & (EndR.Row - 1))
                        'Skip if RCon = MCell
                        If MCell.Value = RCon.Value Then
                        'Skip if this cell and the next are blank
                        ElseIf (RCon.Value = 0 Or RCon.Value = "") And (RCon.Offset(1).Value = 0 Or RCon.Offset(1).Value = "") Then
                        'Add cell contents to MCell
                        Else: MCell.Value = MCell.Value & vbNewLine & RCon.Value
                        End If
                    Next RCon
                'If CCount (Header) is blank, then exit
                ElseIf CCount.Value = 0 Or CCount.Value = "" Then
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next CCount
                
        'Delete extra rows
        If RC + 1 = EndR.Row Then
        ElseIf RC + 1 <> EndR.Row Then Range("'Req Raw'!$A$" & (RC + 1) & ":$A$" & (EndR.Row - 1)).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
        'Set up for next test case
        RC = RC + 1
            'Primary Loop Exit
        If Range("'Req Raw'!$B$" & RC).Value = "" Then Exit Do
    Loop
    
'~~~> For Each Row
'~~~> ID Row (offset by 2 columns) with SectionTitle (Cache A3) + ID starting with 0 on the header
Set RID = Nothing
Set SecT = Range("'Values'!$A$3")
Set RCount = .Range(.Cells(HC, 2), .Cells(.Cells(Rows.count, 2).End(xlUp).Row, 2))
IDCount = 0

For Each RID In RCount
    'ID Req rows
    IDF = CStr(IDCount)
    IDF = Format(IDF, "0000")
    RID.Offset(columnOffset:=-1).Value = SecT.Value & " " & IDF
'~~~> Add ID, ReqName, Section to Values sheet where if ID is 0 then Type = Folder
        Set VSection = Worksheets("Values").Cells(Worksheets("Values").Cells(Rows.count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 2)
        VSection.EntireRow.ClearContents
        Set VName = Worksheets("Values").Cells(Worksheets("Values").Cells(Rows.count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 3)
        Set VType = Worksheets("Values").Cells(Worksheets("Values").Cells(Rows.count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 4)
        Set VID = Worksheets("Values").Cells(Worksheets("Values").Cells(Rows.count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 5)
    'Row = Header where IDCount = 0
        If IDCount = 0 Then
        VSection.Value = SecT.Value
        VName.Value = SecT.Value
        VType.Value = "Folder"
        VID.Value = IDCount
    'Row <> Header where IDCount > 0
        ElseIf IDCount > 0 Then
        VSection.Value = SecT.Value
            If InStr(1, RID.Offset(columnOffset:=1).Value, vbCrLf) <> 0 And (InStr(1, RID.Offset(columnOffset:=1).Value, vbCrLf) - 1) >= 10 Then
                VName.Value = RID.Value & " " & Left(RID.Offset(columnOffset:=1).Value, InStr(1, RID.Offset(columnOffset:=1).Value, vbCrLf) - 1)
            Else: VName.Value = RID.Value & " " & RID.Offset(columnOffset:=1).Value
            End If
            VName.Value = Replace(VName.Value, vbCrLf, " ")
            VName.Value = Replace(VName.Value, "  ", " ")
        VName.WrapText = False
        VID.Value = IDCount
        End If
    IDCount = IDCount + 1
Next RID

'~~~> Sort DRS by ID
.Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, .Cells(2, Columns.count).End(xlUp).Column)).Sort key1:=.Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, 1)), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
'~~~> Sort Values sheet range by ID
With Worksheets("Values")
.Range(.Cells(15, 2), .Cells(50000, 12)).Sort key1:=.Range(.Cells(15, 2), .Cells(50000, 2)), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
End With

End With
'~~~> Reset
Unload Me
Unload ReqUploadForm
ReqUploadForm.Show

'~~~> Clear Cache
Dim Cache As Range
Set Cache = Range("'Values'!$A$3:$D$12")
Cache.ClearContents

End Sub
```

Comment: It shouldn't happen. May I see your workbook?

Comment: Added code leading up to issue

Comment: No. I want to see your workbook. I want to check those shapes

Comment: The For Each code worked fine for me deleting 10 circles. I tried it using the with statement and it seemed to work too.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're using `'~~~> Set Active Sheet to Req Raw
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Req Raw")` if you don't actually use it but for one line `'Unmerge cells .Cells.UnMerge`

Comment: This is a partial sample of the script leading up until the problem. The rest of the script does not trigger due to the error presented at delete line. I'll post the full sub but the rest of the script after the line does not run due to the error.

I should clarify again that I've run this code before and it worked fine until suddenly this error presented. I had not touched or altered that specific section. I've tried to run this code on a sheet with no shapes at all and it still presents an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like deleting pictures seperately before deleting all shapes addresses the issue. Below is the code I used.

```
'Delete all objects on sheet
.Pictures.Delete
For i = .Shapes.count To 1 Step -1
    .Shapes(i).Delete
Next
```