# VBA delete all shapes error

Tags: vba, excel

I noticed my worksheet was slowing right down, and found a few objects had been created for some reason. I ran the following macro to remove them all:

```
Dim Shp as Shape
For Each Shp In Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes
    Shp.Delete
Next Shp
```

However I keep getting `The index into the specified collection is out of bounds` error. So I did the following to see how many objects had been created:

```
Dim i As Long
i = ActiveSheet.Shapes.Count
MsgBox CLng(i)
```

And received the number 41152. I have tried `Go To Special` and selected objects, but if this number is correct my computer is crashing trying to select over 41K objects at once.

Any suggestions how to remove them all?

Comment: curious that you have `41152` shapes on your sheet! and also that the first bit of code fails. What happens if you try stepping backward through the shapes (like this: `For x = i To 0 Step -1: Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes(x).Delete: Next`)

Comment: Gets the same error this way too. I wonder if it can't handle deleting this many at once. Is there a way I can limit it to the first 1000 or so? Will happily run it 40 times if it gets rid of them!

Comment: Try `Activesheet.DrawingObjects.Delete`?

Comment: you can limit to the first *n* number by changing my first step to this `For x = i to 1000: Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes(x).Delete: Next`. Although, you may need to Step backward for this to work (like I did above ...`For x = i to i - 1000 Step -1`). I have a suspicion that there is something corrupt in the shapes, though, which is preventing it from working as it should.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30330897/excel-vba-deleting-objects-from-sheet-triggers-run-time-error

Comment: Ok I got it with `i = ActiveSheet.Shapes.Count: For x = i To 1 Step -1: Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes(x).Delete: Next` so thanks for that @ScottHoltzman !

Comment: @TimWilkinson - great, that is what I was suggesting in my first post. (I was taking for granted that `i` was set as you already had in your code above :) ... that's what I get for assuming :) ... ah, yes, i see as well. I couldn't remember if the `shapes` collection was `1` or `0` based array.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman could you post your solution as an answer?

Comment: @TimWilkinson - Done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can step backward through the `Shapes` collection to delete them from the last value in the collection `Index` to the first.

Like this:

```
i = Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes.Count
For x = i To 1 Step -1: Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes(x).Delete: Next
```